# Solder paste issues

Tags: soldering, reflow, solder-paste

I am using the smallest sized readily available [lead paste](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=-959&y=-71&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=SMD291AX250T5-ND) I could find (15-25 micron size) and printing using a metal stencil with the smallest pitch being .5mm pitch qfns. Reflow is with a [SMTmax](http://www.smtmax.com/detail.php?id=225) oven, with max temp around 240C.

The problem I am having is leftover solder bb's, which can be washed off with denatured alcohol, albeit with difficulty.  The joints seems secure, even though they don't look right.  Adding flux and reflowing with my benchtop reflow doesn't reflow these bb's, even getting it much hotter than the oven.

Could this just be a bad batch of solder?

Is this typical of fine screen solder paste?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image]

Comment: Smells like you got an old batch.

Comment: My experience with chipquick is the low temp rework stuff.   I didn't know they made paste.  I don't trust those joints at all.  Rule 1 of soldering is that if it doesn't look right, it isn't.

Comment: I don't think they actually make it, but its semi-rebranded stuff from amtech solder.  I know its not right, its annoying.  Coarser grained stuff doesn't print right either.

Comment: It looks to me like your flux has been activated, but the solder hasn't gone eutectic.  Either your temp controller isn't right, its not lead-tin, or the flux has gone bad.  Can you check with a thermistor?  Has this oven ever worked for any paste?  Do the joints improve if you touch them up with an iron?

Comment: I can't check with a thermistor, but I know its getting hot enough, I am having rated parts that are melting at 250C setting, and the joints look the same.  I have had better luck with other paste.